# In-place methods in subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, subclass, in-place

I am trying to subclass `list` in order to create an in-place method that updates `self` with the item-wise sum of it*self* and a new list. Example:

This is how I tried to do it:

```
class RecordBook(list):
    def accumulate(self, new_values):
        self = RecordBook([x+y for x, y in zip(self, new_values)])
```

With the though being that rebinding back to `self` will modify it in-place. It does not work however.

```
>> d = RecordBook([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>> d
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>> d.accumulate([1]*6)
>> d
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  # should have been [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Why is that failing the task and how would one go about this?

Comment: You're not *modifying* the instance, you're trying to *replace* the instance with a completely new instance. Don't do that. You want something like `self[:] = [...]` to modify an existing list.

Comment: @deceze You are totally right but I still don't get why it did not work

Comment: You probably want to subclass [`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) i/o `list`

Comment: Because `self` is just a local variable, and assigning something else to it doesn't replace the existing object. `a = 'foo'; b = a; b = 42` — Did that replace or modify `a`? Nope.

Comment: "but I still don't get why it did not work" Because nothing in Python ever works that way. If you do `a = []` and `b = a` and then `b = 3`, `a` does not become `3`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If these two examples are equivalent, my understanding of `self` was flawed. Thanks!

Comment: `self` is just another parameter. The magic is done [elsewhere](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach subclassing [`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList), and modifying the underlying `self.data` of the subclass.

As explained by @Deceze in the comments:

> self is just a local variable, and assigning something else to it doesn't replace the existing object

`UserList` exposes the [`self.data`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList.data) attribute that can be modified "in-place"

```
from collections import UserList


class Accumulator(UserList):
    def accumulate(self, seq):
        for idx, elt in enumerate(seq):
            self.data[idx] += elt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = Accumulator([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    d.accumulate([1]*6)
    print(d)
```

#### output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```